# NUnit TestCase Cannot Refer to Instance Member

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, nunit, instance

I'm trying to `SetUp` an object for use in some `Visual Basic` `NUnit` integration tests similarly to how I've done it before in `C#`.

```
Public Class ApprovalLevelTests

Private myLevel As ApprovalLevel= Nothing

<SetUp>
Public Function Setup()
    myLevel = ApprovalLevel.GetApprovalLevel(1, "414", "MKRT")
End Function

Public Sub TearDown()

End Sub

<TestCase(myLevel.Basic, "<=$1,000")>
<TestCase(myLevel.Middle, "$1,000-$5,000")>
Public Sub AutoApprovalRange_ValidRanges_ReturnsTrue(ByVal approvalRange As String, ByVal limit As String)
```

But Visual Studio complains that `myLevel` cannot be used in the test case because you cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer. Im a bit confused because I tried doing this by passing string literals and it still got upset. If I do it this way, it works no problem.

```
Public Sub AutoApprovalRange_ValidRanges_ReturnsTrue()
    ApprovalLevel level = ApprovalLevel.GetApprovalLevel(1, "414", "MKRT");
    Assert.IsTrue(level.Basic == "(Limit: <=$1,000)");
    Assert.IsTrue(level.Middle == "(Limit: $1,000-$5,000)");
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Could you post `C#` equivalent of the provided `VB` code? The problem is that you access `myLevel` variable in the `TestCase` attribute. I think that in you sample you should declare only one `TestCase` attribute: `<TestCase("<=$1,000", "$1,000-$5,000")>`. Please, try it.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev In C#, just replace the angle brackets with square brackets, and `Sub` turns into a `void` function.

Answer (score 1):

As you may already know, the descriptions that you provide in angle brackets are .NET Attributes.  This is a general feature that the unit testing machinery uses to identify and configure tests.  Attributes are effectively `Shared` as they are a property of the routine across all classes.  In fact, they go farther than being `Shared` as they are a property of the language item in the assembly.

As a consequence of this, the C# documentation on attributes explicitly states that attribute arguments must be compile-time constants.  You can find the C# documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes

I did not find anything equivalent in the VB documentation of attributes, but I wouldn't think this would be language-specific.  It's a natural conclusion of what attributes are and how they are processed by the compiler.